# sqlite - find recipes that can be made from a set of ingredients

Tags: sql, sqlite, relational-database, tagging

Right now I am using sqlite within a ios application, and I want to be able to search for recipes that can be made from a list of ingredients (ie recipes such that are a subset of the provided ingredients)

For example:

```
Recipe 1: A B C
Recipe 2: A B
Recipe 3: C D
Recipe 4: A
Recipe 5: E

Query for ingredients A B C returns recipes {1, 2, 4}
Query for ingredients A B returns recipes {2, 4}
Query for ingredients D returns {}
```

Currently what I have set up is

```
Table Items
name text primary key

Table Recipes
ID required_item integer, recipe_name text
```

I can easily do queries for recipes containing any of the three ingredients and queries for recipes containing all of the three ingredients, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do queries for only

```
Recipes ∈ P(Ingredients)
```

Sorry, I'm new to database programming, and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `left join` to a search table.  Then `group by` recipe.  Use a `having` clause to demand that for each recipe, there are no ingredients that are not in the search list.  For example:

```
select  ri.RecipeNr
from    RecipeIngredients ri
left join
        (
        select  'A' as Ingredient
        union all
        select  'B'
        union all
        select  'C'
        ) search
on      ri.Ingredient = search.Ingredient
group by
        ri.RecipeNr
having  count(case when search.Ingredient is null then 1 end) = 0
```

[Live example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/aa772/29/0)