# Using Checkboxes with JQuery

Tags: jquery, sqlite, input, checkbox

I'm trying to search a database of desserts based on what ingredients the user has. By using 'and' in my query, even if a user checks all available ingredients, it doesn't output any desserts from the database (because none of the desserts use all of the ingredients). The database table has null for the ingredients columns that a dessert doesn't have. How can I adjust my code so that it will show all of the desserts that only use the ingredients input by the user?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1> Immediate Ingredients </h1>
    
    <form>
        Eggs <input type="checkbox" name="eggs" value="yes">
        Chocolate Chips <input type="checkbox" name="cchip" value="yes">
        Butter <input type="checkbox" name="butter" value="yes">
        Sugar <input type="checkbox" name="sugar" value="yes">
        Flour <input type="checkbox" name="flour" value="yes">
        Vanilla <input type="checkbox" name="vanilla" value="yes">
        Heavy Cream <input type="checkbox" name="hc" value="yes">
        Baking Powder <input type="checkbox" name="bpowder" value="yes">
        Peanut Butter <input type="checkbox" name="pbutter" value="yes">
        Powdered Sugar<input type="checkbox" name="psugar" value="yes">
        Fruit <input type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="yes">
        
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

<?php
$eggs=$_GET['eggs'];
$cchip=$_GET['cchip'];
$butter=$_GET['butter'];
$sugar=$_GET['sugar'];
$flour=$_GET['flour'];
$vanilla=$_GET['vanilla'];
$hc=$_GET['hc'];
$bpowder=$_GET['bpowder'];
$pbutter=$_GET['pbutter'];
$psugar=$_GET['psugar'];
$fruit=$_GET['fruit'];


$database = new PDO('sqlite:ingredients.db');
$result = $database->query("SELECT * FROM ingredients_data WHERE eggs='{$eggs}' AND cchip='{$cchip}' AND butter='{$butter}' AND sugar='{$sugar}' AND flour='{$flour}' AND vanilla='{$vanilla}' AND hc='{$hc}' AND bpowder='{$bpowder}' AND pbutter='{$pbutter}' AND psugar={$psugar}' AND fruit='{$fruit}'");
$data = $result->fetchAll (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    foreach($data as $row_index => $ingredients){
    $row_number = $row_index + 1;
        
    echo "<h1> {$row_number}</h1>";
    echo "<h2> {$ingredients['dname']} </h2>";
    }
    


?>

</body>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11066631/sqlite-find-recipes-that-can-be-made-from-a-set-of-ingredients And, this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114407/save-result-checkboxes-checked-in-form-into-sqlite-database-with-javascript

Comment: This might help with the NULL value part. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067215/unchecked-checkbox-returning-null-value

Comment: Maybe this helps too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272247/how-to-build-an-sql-query-from-html-checkboxes

Comment: These are very helpful! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use OR rather than AND? In this way all deserts that contains at least once ingredient (selected by the user) will show.

Comment: What about the IN operator?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I want the program to display only the desserts that use the ingredients checked off. For example, if a user doesn't have eggs but has butter, I don't want it to display desserts that have butter and eggs.

Comment: Do you know what a SQL Injection is?  Please don't do this until you fully understand the security issues.